# Название Маросейка

Tags: топонимика

Часто слышу название этой московской улицы, но что оно означает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего - окказиональное образование, стяжение от Малороссия, малороссийский.
На этой улице находилось малоросиийское подворье, где останавливались гетманские посольства.